# How can I use single slot in AWS lex for handling date, duration and a date range?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-lex

I tried custom slot but I got stuck.
If I take input as string and try to convert it into date or duration inside lambda code then how can I capture something like last week or last month

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The built-in date slot is extremely capable and can understand and process utterances like 'next week', 'last month' and provide you with a date in yyyy-mm-dd format.

These inputs are converted into date ranges by Lex. You will need to look through the event payload passed through to your Lambda to better understand this.

By way of example, today is the Thursday, 23rd June 2022. If I use 'next week' as input, Lex will pass in the date of the Sunday of the following week through to the Lambda; i.e.: Sunday, 3 July 2022.

So, 'next month' will returns the last day July and 'next year' will return the last day of 2023.

Please note that this is slightly different to what the documentation currently says. The documentation claims that the date will be of the starting Monday of the week but our experience has shown it to not be the case.

You will need to test this out in your region and with your date preferences to see how the Lambda works for you.

Please read through the documentation here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lex/latest/dg/built-in-slot-date.html